# getting filename of formdata after axios request

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data

I have a quick question. I would like to extract the file name of a wav file I am passing to my backend through axios using formData. I am not sure how to do this is nodejs. I would appreciate any help

**Frontend:**

```
//file is a Blob
var new_file = new File([file], bucket_string);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("wavfile", new_file, bucket_string);

const config = {
  headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
}

return await axios.post(`/files/upload-file`, formData, config);
//return await axios.post(`http://localhost:2000/files/upload-file`, data);
```

backend:

```
controller.js
async function uploadFile(req, res, next) {
    fileService.uploadFile().then(function(val) {
        res.json(val)
    });
} 

service.js
function uploadFile({ data }) {


const file = data;
var file_name = ?
//i would like to get the file name here

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();
const upload = multer();

function uploadFile(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file.originalname);
    res.json({ok: true}).end();
}

app.post('/', upload.single('wavfile'), uploadFile);

app.listen(3001);
```